# Combinatorics - Closed-Form Expression for Marginal in Chinese Restaurant Process?

Tags: combinatorics, stochastic-processes

I'm trying to calculate a [marginal distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/504251/marginal-distribution-of-last-variable-in-chinese-restaurant-process) and I'm hopeful some result in combinatorics will help.

Suppose we play the following game. I have a sequence of people numbered $z_1, z_2, z_3, ..., z_n$. I take the first person $z_1$ and place them at an empty table with probability $\frac{\alpha}{\alpha}$. For each subsequent person $z_i$, I either place that person at a new table with probability $\frac{\alpha}{i - 1 + \alpha}$ or I place that person at the already-existing $k$th table with probability $\frac{n_k}{i - 1 + \alpha}$, where $n_k$ is the number of people seated at that table. What the probability is that the last person $z_n$ is at a particular table?

To get a sense of the pattern, I'll work out $n=2$ followed by $n=3$ and then give the result for $n=4$.

**Starting with $n=2$:**

$P(z_1=1) = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha}$

$P(z_2=1|z_1 = 1) = \frac{1}{1+\alpha}$

$P(z_2=2|z_1 = 1) = \frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha}$

$P(z_2=1) = P(z_2=1| z_1=1)P(z_1=1) = \frac{\alpha}{(1+\alpha)\alpha}$

$P(z_2=2) = P(z_2=2|z_1=1)P(z_1=1) = \frac{\alpha^2}{(1+\alpha)\alpha}$

**Next with $n=3$:**

$P(z_3=1 | z_1=1, z_2=1) = \frac{2}{2 + \alpha}$

$P(z_3=1 | z_1=1, z_2=2) = \frac{1}{2 + \alpha}$

$P(z_3=2 | z_1=1, z_2=1) = \frac{\alpha}{2 + \alpha}$

$P(z_3=2 | z_1=1, z_2=2) = \frac{1}{2 + \alpha}$

$P(z_3=3 | z_1=1, z_2=2) = \frac{\alpha}{2 + \alpha}$

$P(z_3=1) = P(z_3=1|z_1=1, z_2=1)P(z_2=1|z_1=1)P(z_1=1) + P(z_3=1|z_1=1, z_2=2)P(z_2=2|z_1=1)P(z_1=1) =  \frac{2 \alpha + \alpha^2}{(2+\alpha)(1+\alpha)\alpha}$

$P(z_3=2) = P(z_3=2|z_1=1, z_2=1)P(z_2=1|z_1=1)P(z_1=1) + P(z_3=2|z_1=1, z_2=2)P(z_2=2|z_1=1)P(z_1=1) = \frac{2 \alpha^2}{(2+\alpha)(1+\alpha)\alpha}$

$P(z_3=3) = P(z_3=3|z_1=1, z_2=2)P(z_2=2|z_1=1)P(z_1=1) = \frac{\alpha^3}{(2+\alpha)(1+\alpha)\alpha}$

**The result for $n=4$:**

$P(z_4=1) = \frac{\alpha^3 + 5 \alpha^2 + 6\alpha}{(3+\alpha)(2+\alpha)(1+\alpha)\alpha}$

$P(z_4=2) = \frac{\alpha^3 + 6 \alpha^2}{(3+\alpha)(2+\alpha)(1+\alpha)\alpha}$

$P(z_4=3) = \frac{4 \alpha^3}{(3+\alpha)(2+\alpha)(1+\alpha)\alpha}$

$P(z_4=4) = \frac{\alpha^4}{(3+\alpha)(2+\alpha)(1+\alpha)\alpha}$

I believe the total number of possible outcomes (i.e. the normalizing constant) is given by the [rising factorial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RisingFactorial.html): $\alpha(1+\alpha)(2+\alpha)...(n-1+\alpha)$.

Also, I've noticed two patterns:

1. $P(z_n=n) = \frac{\alpha^n}{\alpha(1+\alpha)(2+\alpha)...(n-1+\alpha)}$. This makes sense because in order for the $n$th person to be at the $n$th table, every previous person must be alone at their respective table.
2. (I'm not sure about this pattern, but it holds through $n=4$): $P(z_n=1) = \frac{\alpha(2+\alpha)...(n-1+\alpha)}{\alpha(1+\alpha)(2+\alpha)...(n-1+\alpha)} = \frac{1}{1+\alpha}$